# is there any way to acess swf embeded in html page from air application? [my air application loads the html page via html loader]

Tags: flash, air

is there any way to acess swf embeded in html page from air application? [my air application loads the html page via html loader]

Answer (score 0):

Did you write the swf? You would use flash.external.ExternalInterface to interact via JavaScript with the swf.